# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation- while creating the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am a beginner in ASP.NET MVC 5 and I was building a small application. While I was adding a controller a message popped up saying: "There was an error running the selected code generator: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation". Before adding the controller I added a connection string in the Web.Config file. Please tell me how to resolve this error.

Comment: Can you please post the code that gives you the error?

Answer (score 2):

There could be a discrepancy between your model and connection string. Have you created a model? If so, then your DbContext class name must match the one specified in your connection string. It's also case sensitive. See the example below.

---Model class---

```
Public Class Model
    Public Property ...
End Class

Public Class ModelDbContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Property Models As DbSet(Of Model)
End Class
```

Make sure to import `Imports System.Data.Entity`

Your connection string should be something like this:

```
<add name="ModelDbContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Models.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set `throwIfV1Schema` to `false` in the constructor of your DbContext, e.g.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) { }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had two connections string with same model but one was with empty "name" and the other one was with the using connectionstring. i remove the empty "name" connectionstring and my issue has resolved.